# How do we calculate thermodynamic properites using VASP 6.1.0?

Tags: vasp

How do we calculate thermodynamic properties using VASP 6.1.0?

Comment: Could you please add what type of thermodynamic properties do you want to know using VASP? And maybe adding the type/name of your material would also help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My question is how do I calculate the thermodynamic properties of the first